# RecyclerView with few child of node firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I'm stopped by a recyclerView error. " cannot convert object String to object Products
My wish is to loop on limited items but there is a string title and a image, [architecture of my firebase data base](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eky7n.png)
Find my code below.

```
        NewsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Products").child("Limited").child("Saint Valentin");

FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Product> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Product>()
                    .setQuery( NewsRef, Product.class )
                    .build();

            FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Product, ProductViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Product, ProductViewHolder>(options) {

                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ProductViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final Product model) {
                    holder.title.setText( model.getTitle() );
                    Picasso.get().load( model.getImage() ).into( holder.image );
                }
```

Of course, there is onCreateViewHolder function below that code..

```
public class Products {

private String title, image, category, date, number;

public Products() {
}

public Products(String title, String image, String category, String date, String number) {
    this.title = title;
    this.image = image;
    this.category = category;
    this.date = date;
    this.number = number;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setLimitedNumber(String number) {
    this.number = number;
}
```

Please anyone has a solution ?

Comment: How is `NewsRef` initialized and please provide a more detailed database schema and indicate what is the exact data you want to display.

Comment: I want to display each element "saint valentin 201x" ...NewsRef is good.
The only problem is that title and image are not type of Products..

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to fetch APIs in wrong way

Change data shown as per below image to fetch the child data(Image is not proper just added for reference)[image]

Json looks something like below

```
{
"Limited": {
"Saint Valentin": [
  {
    "name": "Saint Valentin 2012",
    "image": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com..",
    "title": "Saint Valentin 2012"
  },
  {
    "name": "Saint Valentin 2015",
    "image": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com...",
    "title": "Saint Valentin 2015"
  },
  {
    "name": "Saint Valentin 2017",
    "image": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com...",
    "title": "Saint Valentin 2017"
  }
  ]
  }
  }
```

Comment: I think you don't understand my error..
The  database is right but how can I make a recyclerView without values "title" and "image" , CAn I ? and how?